# iOS - How to ignore the duplicates in NSMutableArray.

Tags: ios

For example I have an array = [12,13,13,13,14,15,16,16,17];

and my output will be 12,13,14,15,16,17.

Please help me on  this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [NSSet](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/) instead, it doesn't allow duplicates.